# Disable emoji picker if built-in emoji keyboard exists

Tags: javascript, html

I've implemented an emoji picker for my website using [emojionearea](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea). However, it would be nice if I could disable it (or certain features) for devices that have a built-in emoji keyboard.

Is there any way I can test for this through the browser? [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) has an emoji test - but that's for checking to see if emoji character sets are supported. Not if there's a built-in emoji data entry option

Comment: This is an interesting question, though I doubt you can test the *input* device. You can test the browser, as you said, but I don't think there's access to input options. (CMIIW) Your best bet might be to check for mobile operating systems as they mostly provide these things, or to test for touch. But even then there will be cases that are not 100% accurate.

Comment: At this stage I've hidden the emoji picker if the user is on a non-desktop os and touch is enabled. I'll re-evaluate this solution if it becomes a difficult problem